# Border-radius Safari

Tags: image, safari, border, css

I am making a banner where people can upload an image.

Before the upload it you see the image. With just a standard html code

```
<div id="box"><img src="blah blah" /></div>
```

The **CSS**:

```
div {
    width:370px;
    height:204px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
}
```

The image will fit in the div id="box" succesfull. If you can see i use border-top-left-radius and right-radius: That works perfect in firefox and Chrome. But in safari it doesnt work.

**Example**:
This is **Chrome** and **Firefox**. You can see the image will fit with the screen and got a nice border-radius on the top.
[image]

This is **Safari**. You see that the image dont have a border-radius on the top. I dont know the problem.
[image]

For that i also tried to use:

```
-webkit-
```

But that also didnt work. Anybody know how to fix that for safari?

Answer (score 0):

please Update Below css and Check .....And make necessary changes as per your requirmnet..

hope this will solve your problem

```
div {
    width:370px;
    height:204px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
}
```

Please Mark answer if your problem is solved...

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work example for if you have safari http://jsfiddle.net/DennisBetman/ZfnPS/ @Javal Patel

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need:

```
div {
width:370px;
height:204px;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
}
```

Keep it simple. :-)

Comment: This didnt work here is an exmaple if you have safari you can test it http://jsfiddle.net/DennisBetman/ZfnPS/ @ralph.m

Comment: You haven't actually tried my suggestion in that fiddle. Just use the border-radius shorthand and you will be fine, even in Safari: `border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;`.

Comment: I tried it with your code see here http://jsfiddle.net/DennisBetman/ZfnPS/9/ in my safari i dont see a border radius on the image. While the image is in the div.

Comment: Your example works perfectly for me in Safari (Mac). Have you refreshed the browser?

Comment: Yeah i refreshed the browser but its still not working. If i cant fix that it isnt the biggest problem but yeah. My version of Safari is Version 5.1.7 (6534.57.2)

Comment: Truly, Safari has no issue with this. It's often good to strip down an example for testing purposes. E.g. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eIhCL

Comment: @ralph.m , Dennis is right, I have the same version of Safari 5.1.7 and here is your link from codepen and his fiddle in one screenshot http://mi-creativity.com/test/images/border_safari_test.jpg

Comment: Ah well, they must have fixed it then, as it certainly works in 6.0.4, which is what I have. Wasn't aware that older versions had an issue with it. (Does anyone even use Safari on desktop now? :D )